# How can I access a Variable outside of a VBScript from another Script?

Tags: javascript, vba, variables, vbscript, ms-word

I created a VBScript that accesses a bookmark in a word document:

```
`Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`
```

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm""")`
    `WScript.Sleep (1000)
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("%m")
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("Beachservices")
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("~")`

I want this part of the code:
    `(C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm)`
 to be a variable that I access outside of this script, so that it would look like:

```
`Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(""Hotel"")
 WScript.Sleep (1000)
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("%m")
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("Beachservices")
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("~")`
```

where Hotel is the variable.

I want this variable to equal the following:

```
`Hotel = C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm`
```

I need to be able to set this variable outside of this script, and be able to access this variable from within this script.

In other words, I want to create a bat or js or a vba or a vbs Script that sets this

```
`Hotel = C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm`
```

Variable, so I can access it from my other scripts.

How do I make this Variable available to other scripts, and how do I access this variable from within the scripts?

I have been working this issue on my own for about 3 months now, and I have been unable to figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a Document Variable or, possibly, a Custom Document Property?

Comment: Well, here is what I am doing: As I am talking on the phone with customers, I am using programable voice commands that activate the scripts. For example, when I say coronado, it opens up the word document in this script. Then when I say the name of the bookmarks, it activates the scripts that go to the  bookmark in question. This way I see the information I am looking for to answer the customers questions, without having to use a mouse or scroll to find the information.

Comment: The issue at hand is that I have about 100 documents like this, and they all have the same name for the bookmarks. So if I can set the document variable when I first open the document needed, then that would set the variable for the bookmark scripts. This way, instead of creating thousands of bookmark scripts, I can use the same scripts that access the variable loaction of the current document at hand. Plus the voice programable software will only let me create 300 custom voice commands.

Comment: So I am trying to create a variable outside of those scripts that can be accessed by those bookmark scripts. I am not a programmer, but through books and research, I have gotten this far. I can do everything I need for one document, but would like to be able to use these commands for the other 99 documents I have.

Comment: You can store Hotel variable in Windows registry or within an specific local file and read its value from script.

Comment: Where is the code which responds to the voice command "Coronado" while none of the documents is open?

Comment: I am using a program called Tazti. So what I do is spell out the voice command, and then give it a script to run. When I say the command it activates the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define Hotel variable in Windows registry. For example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Scott\Hotel

You need a process to set value to Hotel variable:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim oReg
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Scott\"
KeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Scott"
strValueName = "Hotel"
' strValue = "C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm"
strValue =Inputbox("Hotel variable value","Scott program")

' Create key to use
objReg.CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KeyPath)
objReg.SetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue)
```

You must adapt your code to read Hotel variable from registry:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Scott"
strValueName = "Hotel"
strHotel = ""
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strHotel

...

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(strHotel)
 WScript.Sleep (1000)
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("%m")
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("Beachservices")
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("~")`
```

Comment: Ok if i place the variable in the registry, it works, but when I run the script to set up the variable:                                                                          Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim oReg
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Scott\"
KeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Scott"
strValueName = "Hotel"
strValue = "C:\Users\1241\Downloads\HotelDel__advance.docm"
' Create key to use
objReg.CreateKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,KeyPath

Comment: objReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue i get a windows script host error. Line 12 Char 1 Error Object required: 'objReq' Code 800A01A8 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: Thank you so much, all I had to do was go in to the registry and make sure I gave my self permission to change that variable under the scott registry.. Thank you so much indeed. Finally after 3 months of beating my head against the wall, I did it with your help. Thank you so much. It iis really appreciated.